# Notepad++ insert a word in nth character on each line (backwards)

Tags: notepad++

Using Notepad++ Find and Replace feature, I would like to insert a word in nth character of each line from the end.

eg. insert in 8th character from end:

```
cow sheep pig.mp4
dog cat can.mp4
bannana turkey.mp4
```

to

```
cow sheep test pig.mp4
dog cat test can.mp4
bannana turtest key.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `(?m).{7}$` with `test $0`.

Where

- `(?m)` is a [modifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) which activates multiline mode
- `.{7}` means "any 7 characters" (`.` is a generic character)
- `$` matches the end of the line (in multiline mode, otherwise the end of the whole text)
- `$0` references the whole match

Remember to click on "Regular expression"!

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]